# Get loading percent from InputStream .read method

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I have a problem in parsing an InputStream and getting the loading percentage of his data. I mean, my method needs to parse the InputStream, put it into a StringBuffer, get the total of bytes parsed and returns a String based on my StringBuffer.

```
private String processPercent(InputStream content, HttpResponse response) throws IOException
{
    InputStream in = content;
    int totalBytes  = Integer.parseInt(response.getFirstHeader("Content-Length").getValue());
    int processedByte;
    int loaded = 0;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    while((processedByte = in.read()) != -1)
    {

        sb.append((char) processedByte);

        if(this.asyncTask instanceof IProgressPercent)
        {
            lastProcessed = processedByte;
            loaded += processedByte;
            float percent = ((100*loaded) / totalBytes);
            this.progressPercent = (int)percent;
            this.asyncTask.doProgress(this.progressPercent);
        }
    }

    in.close();

    return new String(sb);
}
```

The problem is when I display the value of percent variable, I get a value higher than 100, so I think that's a calculation problem.

Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: Beware that you have much more important problems than your percentage display; see my answer for details

Comment: I've just managed my code with your advices, that's why i've voted your answer up :) Thanks for pointing this out !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
    loaded += processedByte;
```

with

```
++loaded;
```

before the `if` actually; incrementing by 1.

Comment: You are absolutely right ! I was wrong in thinking that was an addition of "processedByte" as the total of downloaded bytes, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems here.

First of all, you are using an `InputStream`; an `InputStream` reads *bytes*. And a `char` **is not** two `byte`s. A `char` is a UTF-16 code unit. See [here](http://fgaliegue.blogspot.com/2014/03/strings-characters-bytes-and-character.html).

Second, you only read byte by byte. If your content length is 1M, you will call this code 1M times. Is this really what you want?

You should change your code in the following ways:

- first of all, use an `InputStreamReader` over your `InputStream` -- *and initiate it with the correct charset*;
- use this reader's `read()` method which reads into a preallocated char array; use the number of *chars* read to update your progress bar;
- add the contents of your `char[]` to your `StringBuffer` (which should really be a `StringBuilder`).

Due to the fact that the decoding process will produce less `char`s than there are actual bytes, this means your counter will be a little off, though; it can be cured using even more sophisticated mechanisms, but this will require quite a bit of code.

Of course, an easier way is, if the size is not too large, download directly all the contents, put it into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` *and then* decoding that `ByteArrayOutputStream`'s content into a `String`.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
float percent = ((100*loaded) / totalBytes);
```

use

```
float percent = 100 * (loaded / totalBytes);
```